# The holiday matching for different states

Tags: r

Currently I have lots of invoice with dates, but they are from different states. I would like to set up a holiday indicator that to check whether the invoice date is a holiday in the corresponding state.

For example I have table A and B as follows, if the date in Table A is the holiday corresponding to the holiday of that state in Table B, the column of the holidayIndicator  should be set to 1, otherwise 0. The return should be a complete table A with 0 or 1 value in the column of holidayIndicator.

```
Table A:
date    state   holidayIndicator
1/1/2018    E   0
2/1/2018    F   0
3/1/2018    G   0
4/1/2018    E   0
5/1/2018    F   0
6/1/2018    G   0

Table B
State   Holiday
E   1/1/2018
E   3/1/2018
E   3/28/2018
F   5/26/2018
F   6/2/2018
F   7/1/2018
G   9/1/2018
G   6/1/2018
G   5/29/2018
```

The result should be like the following

```
date    state   holidayIndicator
1/1/2018    E   1
2/1/2018    F   0
3/1/2018    G   0
4/1/2018    E   0
5/1/2018    F   0
6/1/2018    G   1
```

Comment: Welcome at SO! Someone downvoted you question without leaving a comment why (not really a good welcome culture). Anyhow: Please always add your data (tables) as R code, in your case as `data.frame`, e. g. code like `a <- data.frame(date = c("1/1/2018", "2/1/2018", ...), state = c("E"; "F", "G" ...) ...)` This makes it easier for us to prepare an answer. THX :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the two tables are df1 and df2

df1$holidayIndicator[interaction(df1[, c('date', 'state')]) %in% interaction(df2[, c('Holiday', 'State')])] <- 1

Comment: Thank you!  That's helpful! Just here also need to match the state, i.e., if the row in table A is with state E, it should match the E state calendar in table B, any advice?

Comment: In that case, first, join the two data frames using 'inner_join' on date and State columns. The result will be a data frame. Use this as df2.

Comment: you mean inner_join the two columns in df1? I'm confused, could you please explain more?

Comment: I see the problem with that. You can try using 'interaction'. I will edit the answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with R, but wonder if you could use a package/library like 'bizdays'  to determine if a given date is a holiday or not.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bizdays/bizdays.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A pure `data.frame` based solution (without using the packages `dplyr` or `data.table` would look like this:

```
a <- read.table(text = "date    state   holidayIndicator
1/1/2018    E   0
2/1/2018    F   0
3/1/2018    G   0
4/1/2018    E   0
5/1/2018    F   0
6/1/2018    G   0", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

b <- read.table(text = "State   Holiday
E   1/1/2018
E   3/1/2018
E   3/28/2018
F   5/26/2018
F   6/2/2018
F   7/1/2018
G   9/1/2018
G   6/1/2018
G   5/29/2018", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

b$isHoliday <- 1   # add a helper column (auto-fills all rows with the same value)

# "inner join" similar to SQL to "enrich" the helper column value
res <- merge(a, b, by.x = c("date", "state"), by.y = c("Holiday", "State"), all.x = TRUE)

res$holidayIndicator[res$isHoliday == 1] <- 1  # mark the holidays using the enriched helper column

# Optionally: Remove the helper column from the result
res$isHoliday <- NULL
```